# Accessing a delegate via reflection declared outside of any class?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I am trying a demo for reflection. The assembly I want to reflect in this class goes something like this

```
namespace DelegatesSampleApplication
{
    delegate  bool IsPromotable (Employee employee); // Declaration Syntax is similar to that of a method's 
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             //code goes here
        }
    }

    class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public int Experience { get; set; }

        public void PromoteEmployees(List<Employee> employeeList, IsPromotable isPromotableObj)
        {

            /*foreach (Employee employee in employeeList)
            {
                if (employee.Experience >= 5 && employee.Salary >= 10000) //That's a hard-coded logic that you have developed as a Framework Developer which makes the class itself not reusable
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" {0} will be promoted in the next R.P. Cycle ", employee.EmployeeName);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();*/

            foreach (Employee employee in employeeList)
            {
                if (isPromotableObj(employee)) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" {0} will be promoted in the next R.P. Cycle ", employee.EmployeeName);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem I am facing is, I am trying to read from this assembly in my program and trying to invoke the delegate which takes in a class instance as a parameter.
What I am doing is something like this in a different class altogether

```
  namespace ReflectionSample
{
    delegate bool empIsPromotable (Object obj);
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("***************Loading External assembly*************");
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Users\Chiranjib\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DelegatesSampleApplication\DelegatesSampleApplication\bin\Debug\DelegatesSampleApplication.exe");
            Type employeeType = assembly.GetType("DelegatesSampleApplication.Employee"); //Gets the System.Type object for the Employee Class from the just loaded assembly with all it's dependencies

            Console.WriteLine("***************Loading External assembly properties*************");

           //Setting properties here

            Console.WriteLine("***************Creating an array list that will hold these employee instances***************");
            List<Object> employeeInstanceList = new List<object>();
            employeeInstanceList.Add(employeeInstance);
            employeeInstanceList.Add(employeeInstance2);

            Console.WriteLine("***************Invoking External assembly methods*************");
                        var args = new Object[] {
new List<employeeType>(),
(((employeeInstance) => { return true; }))
```

};

```
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

This throws error. Saying employeeType missing an assembly reference. Also I cannot convert a lambda expression into an object. I cannot directly type cast to (IsPromotable) right ? I am using reflection. So I am supposed not to have a direct access.

How would I be able to access the delegate via reflection ? 
Please help me through. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to do dependency injection? Like build a dependency resolver?

Answer (score 4):

`IsPromotable` is not invokeable, it's simply a delegate definition. Think of it like an interface. It just tells you what the method takes and returns, but does not actually *do* anything.

You can call `PromoteEmployees` like this:

```
PromoteEmployees(new List<Employee>, (employee) => { return employee.Name == "Rob"; });
```

Any method which matches the signature of `IsPromotable` is a valid parameter to the method (ie, any method that takes an `Employee` and returns a `bool`). Could you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to do, exactly?

If you just want a list of delegates, you can do this:

```
GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubClassOf(typeof(BaseDelegate)));
```

Note; this will only return the delegates in your current assembly. You might want to change it to:

```
typeof(Employee).GetTypes().Assembly.Where(t => t.IsSubClassOf(typeof(BaseDelegate)));
```

To get all methods in an assembly which are castable to `IsPromotable`, you can do this:

```
var delegateMethod = typeof(IsPromotable).GetMethod("Invoke");

var @params = delegateMethod.GetParameters();
var returnType = delegateMethod.ReturnType;

var matchingMethods = typeof(IsPromotable)
    .Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods())
    .Where(m => {
        if (m.ReturnType != returnType)
            return false;
        var currParams = m.GetParameters();
        if (currParams.Length != @params.Length)
            return false;
        for(var i = 0; i < currParams.Length;i++)
            if (currParams[i] != @params[i])
                return false;

        return true;
    });
```

To invoke the method with reflection, you can do this:

```
var args = new Object[] {
    new List<Employee>(),
    ((IsPromotable)((emp) => { return true; }))
};

var value = employeeType.InvokeMember("PromoteEmployees", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, employeeInstance, args);
```

Or, you can just pass it a regular method:

```
var args = new Object[] {
    new List<Employee>(),
    ((IsPromotable)Test)
};

var value = employeeType.InvokeMember("PromoteEmployees", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, employeeInstance, args);
```

With the method:

```
private bool Test(Employee emp)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have modified the question details. Thanks for the input any ways. But If I want to invoke the method via employeeType.InvokeMember("PromoteEmployees", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, employeeInstance, new Object[] {}) the thing is that it takes objects as parameters but lambda expression now cannot be passed as a parameter . Can you help ?

Comment: That does solve the problem Sir. 
But List<Employee> hopefully I can't directly get a reference to right ? I have been using Reflection . So  Type employeeType = assembly.GetType("DelegatesSampleApplication.Employee") gives me the type object. But List<employeeType> says I am missing a assembly reference.